# Error receiving broadcast Intent when using SmsRetriever

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, broadcastreceiver, sms-retriever-api

When authenticating using Firebase Auth, I want to auto input the code that is received via SMS. I am able to receive SMS and go through auth process manually, but when I use SmsRetriever, the app crashes and then the bottom sheet dialog shows up. This is everything that that appears in Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED flg=0x200010 pkg=com.finca.bank (has extras) } in com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvb@45fb8c5
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1566)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.CharSequence.length()' on a null object reference
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:280)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:186)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1034)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvd.zzf(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvb.onReceive(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.1:8)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1556)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
```

This is code inside my Fragment that receives SMS:

```
private val SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST = 2  // Set to an unused request code

    private val smsVerificationReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            try {
                if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent.action) {
                    val extras = intent.extras
                    val smsRetrieverStatus = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

                    when (smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode) {
                        CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                            // Get consent intent
                            val consentIntent = extras.getParcelable<Intent>(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT)
                            try {
                                // Start activity to show consent dialog to user, activity must be started in
                                // 5 minutes, otherwise you'll receive another TIMEOUT intent
                                startActivityForResult(consentIntent, SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST)
                            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                                // Handle the exception ...
                            }
                        }
                        CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                            // Time out occurred, handle the error.
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e(e, "onReceive: ")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val task = SmsRetriever.getClient(requireActivity()).startSmsUserConsent(null)
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
        requireActivity().registerReceiver(smsVerificationReceiver, intentFilter)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        requireActivity().unregisterReceiver(smsVerificationReceiver)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            // ...
            SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST ->
                // Obtain the phone number from the result
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    // Get SMS message content
                    val message = data.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE)
                    // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                    // `message` contains the entire text of the SMS message, so you will need
                    // to parse the string.
                    message?.let { presenter.parseSms(it) }
                    // send one time code to the server
                } else {
                    // Consent denied. User can type OTC manually.
                }
        }
    }
```

Interesting thing is, the progress goes successfully in rare cases and I don't know what it depends on. Also, everything goes well in debug mode if breakpoints are set in `onReceive`

Comment: Did you find the way how to fix it? Because I faced the same problem and I dont know, how to solve this, because I obtain internal error from "com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api"

Comment: @AlexD. Sadly, no. For now I've decided to live without the SmsRetriever.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. The default sms-retreval by firebase phone auth is not working. Thats why I tried putting a custom sms retriver and got same crash.

Comment: Do you try to move register broadcast receiver into onCreate and unregister in onStop? I think main problem come from the lifecycle state

Comment: You all are using it on emulator or real device?

Comment: I want to see your sms format

Comment: @Steve.P Yes, I've tried that. I've also tried moving all the SmsRetriever code into the next activity(where users input the code)

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I've tried doing it on several real devices. SMS format is the default Firebase Auth SMS format. %LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for the app %APP_NAME%.

Comment: anybody found an answer?

Comment: I am facing this issue too. Any solutions?

Answer (score 16):

After several investigations, the root cause of this crash seems to be related to a conflict between Firebase Auth [Instant Verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential) feature and [SMS consent API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request).

In order to fix it you have two options:

1. Remove SMS consent API and only rely on Instant Verification
2. Use SMS Consent API and disable Instant Verification by setting timeout as 0. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthOptions.Builder#setTimeout(java.lang.Long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Hope this provides some clarity around this weird issue.

Comment: it worked for me when after setting timeout time as 0

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Got the same error while Integrating the SMS consent API. After Searching and modification got a solution. In the below-attached image, you can see the setTimeout method consists of a parameter called timeout, change that parameter value from 60L to 0L. For more info about the method [click here!](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth?authuser=2&hl=en)

[image: Just change that value from 60L to 0L.]

Answer (score -1):

To automatically verify phone numbers, you must implement both the client and server portions of the verification flow. You just implemented the client portion. To listen to SMS and auto input the OTP code you have to also implement the server side. A complete guide is found here [Perform SMS Verification on a Server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify)

Comment: @Muhammedshamshadp Sorry about that. I've edited my answer and put the correct link.